# How to make a custom search by spring-data-jpa framework?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I am very new to use spring-data-jpa, but it looks very promising. I used it to make all repository in my application like this:
 `public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer>`

I see that there is a methode call `findAll(Specification<T>)` to make custom search.to call this you should implement the 
`public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> q, CriteriaBuilder cb)`
I am very confused to how to make a predicate. I try to use the example on [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

```
  public static Specification<Customer> isLongTermCustomer() {
return new Specification<Customer>() {
  Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        CriteriaBuilder builder) {

     LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
     return builder.lessThan(root.get(Customer_.createdAt), date);
  }
};
```

}
I dont understand where `Customer_.createdAt`came from. Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Customer_` comes from JPA 2.0 static metamodel that should be generated by a special tool such as [Hibernate Metamodel generator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html).

If you don't want to generate static metamodel, you can do the following instead:

```
return builder.lessThan(root.<LocalDate>get("createdAt"), date);
```

Comment: Thanks:) i tried to use the hibernate-jpamodelgen. It generates the metamodel but it puts it in the target directory. There is a guid here to how to use it in eclipse.http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html/chapter-usage.html#d0e325 I use Eclipse Helios and i dont find annotation processing there. do you know how i can include it in my class path here is my plugin

Comment: '<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <compilerArguments>

      <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>

     </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>'